React typescript Error: 'map doesnt exist on type [type]' here type is an array of objects. why?
I get the following error and just dont understand why:
map does not exist on type DataItemList
export interface DataItemList {
    'performanceTimePointList'?: Array<DataItem>;
}

export interface DataItem {
  title: string,
  ...
}

Does not work and gives error:
  const convertToChartData = async (data: DataItemList) => {
    console.log("???", data);
    const performanceData = data.map(() => data.title)
}

Does work:
  const convertToChartData = async (data: DataItem[]) => {
    console.log("???", data);
    const performanceData = data.map(() => data.title)
}

I dont understand why the second one works, as writing DataItem[] is only saying its an array with DataItem(s) and DataItemnList is the array.

data.performanceTimePointList is the array, not data itself. You want this version. Does that fully address the question?

An object which contains an array property is not an array.

The issue is from the type definition in your convertToChartData function. In your first example, data is of type DataItemList, which has an optional property performanceTimePointList of type Array. This means that data itself is not an array but an object, so calling .map() directly on data will not work.
on other hand, your second example works because you are directly specifying that data is an array of DataItem, allowing you to use the .map() method.
To fix the first case, you should map over data.performanceTimePointList if it exists.
const convertToChartData = async (data: DataItemList) => {
   console.log("???", data);
   const performanceData = data.performanceTimePointList?.map(item => item.title) || [] }

Hope it help you

ohh thanks. I didnt understand the part that DataItemList is an object containing an array. A question: Why couldnt I also specify it like this: async (data: DataItemList.performanceTimePointList) => ... ? I checked and I cant but is there any way to specify it similar?

Also if I do it like you suggested, Im getting another strange error: Object is possibly undefined

@Julia: Which specific object is possibly undefined?  Are you asking how to handle an undefined value in that case, or are you indicating that you expect the object to never be undefined?  If this is related to the question above, please clarify.  If this is a different problem on a different operation then it may warrant a new Stack Overflow question.
